# Select and copy text without linebreaks in andoird

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, copy-paste

How can I display text in Android/Kotlin that has line breaks but when the users selects and copies it there are no line breaks in the clipboard?

That is, if I have:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/recognized_text"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        />
```

and let's say the text is

text = "a string with \n some text"

then the view should show two rows like

```
a string with
some text
```

but when I select the text I should get:

```
a string with some text
```

in the clipboard (with no line breaks). The user may select only part of the text as well so keep that in mind. We don't need to use `TextView` specifically if there is a better way. It also should use the same copy selection button when you long press on text like TextView generally with the regular pop-up menu

I considered using "
" instead of "/n" but I can't find any documentation on if that would change anything. I don't think it would.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code you can try for your desire result

first convert your text into spannable string

```
 private fun getClickableSpannable(text: String): CharSequence {
        val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(text)

        // Create a ClickableSpan to manipulate clipboard content
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                // Extract the clicked text without line breaks
                val selectedText = (widget as TextView).text.subSequence(
                    widget.selectionStart,
                    widget.selectionEnd
                ).toString().replace("\n", "")

                // Copy the cleaned text to the clipboard
                val clipboard =
                    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Cleaned Text", selectedText)
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            }
        }

        // Apply the ClickableSpan to the entire text
        spannable.setSpan(
            clickableSpan,
            0,
            text.length,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )

        return spannable
    }
```

after that in your textview give link movement

```
recognizedText.text = getClickableSpannable(text)
recognizedText.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
```

[image]

Comment: will this show the selection pop-up menu, or does it just copy the text? Like will it show copy, select all, share ect?

Comment: yes it will show

Comment: when you click copy it copies the "\n" as well. Its only when you click that this works

Answer (score 0):

```
val textToCopy = originalText.replace(Regex("[\\n]"), "")

val clipboardManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", textToCopy)
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
```

To copy and replace the new lines

Comment: will this show the selection pop-up menu, or does it just copy the text? Like will it show copy, select all, share ect?

Comment: no, It will copy the text you want you can select the text view or edit text box from where you want to select the text